# SQLSetStmtOption Option '5' is not supported

Tags: javascript, npm, odbc, adonis.js, transoft

Hello fellow developers!
I'm trying to make a query to a database through the odbc package https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc.
I am able to do it through FlySpeed SQL Query, but when I try to query from the package I get the error:

```
[Error: [odbc] Error preparing for fetch] {
    odbcErrors: [
        {
            state: 'HYC00',
            code: 0,
            message: "[Transoft][TSODBC][usqlsd]SQLSetStmtOption Option '5' is not supported "
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my controller (From an adonisjs v4 api):

```
"use strict";

const odbc = require("odbc");

class OdbcController {
    async fetchData() {
        odbc.connect('DSN=triad.udd;', (error, connection) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
            let sql = "Select Customer From m.POS_ARC_D_HEAD;"
            connection.query(sql, (error, result) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
                console.log('result', result)  
            })
        });
    }
}

module.exports = OdbcController;
```

I am able to connect to the database. I also tried misspelling the table and it gave me the error that the table does not exist (showing that it is really connected and able to, kind of, query), but when the table does exist, I get the error mentioned earlier plus this error (after like 3 seconds this log appears and my app crashes):

/c/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/npm: line 44:  1226 Segmentation fault      "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"

The docs for the odbc driver are here (I think?):
http://pz.southware.com/nlhtml/USQL_User_Guide.pdf

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Note that the Transoft ODBC Driver is in 32bit and so is my nodejs. I was getting compatibility issues otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone faces this issue, I was using version 2.4.6 of the odbc package. Downgrading it to 2.2.0 worked for me. I did not try with other versions. Not sure what caused the error.